# Why doesn't the POSIX API have an end-of-file function?

Tags: posix, eof, posix-api

In the POSIX API, `read()` returns 0 to indicate that the end-of-file has been reached.  Why isn't there a separate function that tells you that `read()` would return zero -- without requiring you to actually call `read()`?

---

Reason for asking: Since you have to call `read()` in order to discover that it will fail, this makes file reading algorithms more complicated and maybe slightly less efficient since they have to allocate a target buffer that may not be needed.

What we might like to do...

```
while ( !eof )
   {
   allocate buffer
   read to buffer
   process buffer
   }
```

What we have to do instead...

```
while ( true )
   {
   allocate buffer
   read to buffer
   if ( eof ) release buffer, break;
   process buffer
   }
```

---

Additionally, it seems like this behavior propagates itself into higher-level APIs such as `fread()` and `feof()` in C -- and creates a lot of confusion about how to use `feof()` correctly:

- C: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)
- C++: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)
- Python: [How to loop until EOF in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752107/how-to-loop-until-eof-in-python)

Comment: The most interesting answer that I have seen (to a similar question): http://stackoverflow.com/a/5605161/86967.  Need to think about whether or not similar logic is applicable to the POSIX API.

Comment: The case where the input stream size is an exact multiple of the buffer size is generally rare.  Therefore, end-of-stream isn't particularly helpful under typical scenarios.  I don't recall exactly, but at the time I asked this question, I may have been working with a case in which the stream was made up of packets/chunks of a very specific size (which was also large enough to be significant).

Answer (score 6):

To gain perspective on why this might be the case, understand that **end-of-stream is not inherently a permanent situation**.  A file's read pointer could be at the end, but if more data is subsequently appended by a write operation, then subsequent reads will succeed.

Example: In Linux, when reading from the console, a new line followed by `^D` will cause `posix::read()` to return zero (indicating "end of file").  However, if the program isn't terminated, the program can continue to read (assuming additional lines are typed).

Since end-of-stream is not a permanent situation, perhaps it makes sense to not even have an is_at_end() function (POSIX does not). Unfortunately, this does put some additional burden on the programmer (and/or a wrapper library) to elegantly and efficiently deal with this complexity.