# Get output from a Paramiko SSH exec_command continuously

Tags: python, ssh, stdout, paramiko, interactive

I am executing a long-running python script via ssh on a remote machine using paramiko. Works like a charm, no problems so far.

Unfortunately, the `stdout` (respectively the `stderr`) are only displayed after the script has finished! However, due to the execution time, I'd much prefer **to output each new line as it is printed**, not afterwards.

```
remote = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote.connect("host", username="uname", password="pwd")
 
# myScript produces continuous output, that I want to capture as it appears    
stdin, stdout, stderr = remote.exec_command("python myScript.py")
stdin.close()
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print(line)
```

**How can this be achieved?** *Note: Of course one could pipe the output to a file and 'less' this file via another ssh session, but this is very ugly and I need a cleaner, ideally pythonic solution :)*

Comment: just to help others in future, myScript.py should contain sys.stdout.flush()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As specified in the [read(*[size]*) documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read), if you don't specify a `size`, it reads until EOF, that makes the script wait until the command ends before returning from `read()` and printing any output.

Check this answers: [How to loop until EOF in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1752208/236871) and [How to do a "While not EOF"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599648/236871) for examples on how to exhaust the File-like object.

Comment: thanks @KurzedMetal for pointing me in the right direction:
`for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(2048), ""):
                    print(line, end="")`
... did the trick!

Answer (score 32):

A minimal and complete working example of how to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39231690/931303) (tested in Python 3.6.1)

```
# run.py
from paramiko import SSHClient

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()

ssh.connect('...')

print('started...')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python -m example', get_pty=True)

for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line, end="")
print('finished.')
```

and

```
# example.py, at the server
import time

for x in range(10):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(2)
```

run on the local machine with

```
python -m run
```

Comment: With `get_pty=True`, error is not returned to `stderr`, but it is printed directly to the terminal. Having hard time to resolve that.

Comment: can you please explain how iter(stdout.readline, "") works ?

Answer (score 11):

I was facing a similar issue. I was able to solve it by adding get_pty=True to paramiko:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("/var/mylongscript.py", get_pty=True)
```

Comment: 'get_pty' is shown in the paramiko doc's function signature, but isn't explained anywhere. Do you have any insight what it does? https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html

Comment: My best guess is "get pseudo terminal"

Comment: @JamesShrum is correct, 2.6 has it documented as "Request a pseudo-terminal from the server" https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.6/api/client.html

Answer (score 5):

using this:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python -m example', get_pty=True)

for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line, end="")
```

from @JorgeLeitao 's answer sped my stdout output up to almost real-time!!

I was using:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
for line in stdout:
    # Process each line in the remote output
        print (line)
```

Answer (score 3):

Streaming response data from a generator function.

I wanted to make a class that had more complexity than the standard Client.exec_command() examples and less than what I was seeing for Channel.exec_command() examples. Plus I covered some 'gotchas' that I encountered.  This summary script was tested on CentOS Stream - Python 3.6.8.

```
import sys
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys('/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts')

try:
    client.connect('host', username='username', password='password',
        port=22, timeout=2)
except Exception as _e:
    sys.stdout.write(_e)

# is_active can be a false positive, so further test
transport = client.get_transport()
if transport.is_active():
    try:
        transport.send_ignore()
    except Exception as _e:
        sys.stdout.write(_e)
        sys.exit(1)
else:
   sys.exit(1)

channel = transport.open_session()
# We're not handling stdout & stderr separately
channel.set_combine_stderr(1)
channel.exec_command('whoami')
# Command was sent, no longer need stdin
channel.shutdown_write()

def responseGen(channel):
    # Small outputs (i.e. 'whoami') can end up running too quickly
    # so we yield channel.recv in both scenarios
    while True:
        if channel.recv_ready():
            yield channel.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')

        if channel.exit_status_ready():
            yield channel.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
            break

# iterate over each yield as it is given 
for response in responseGen(channel):
    sys.stdout.write(response)

# We're done, explicitly close the conenction
client.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answers all use `exec_command`, they would be useful if you also use this way. But if you try `send()` with `invoke_shell()` they will not be useful. In that way, you can try this

```
while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        backMsg = ""
        try:
            backMsg = self.channel.recv(65536).decode('utf-8')
        except socket.timeout as e:
            break
        print 'backMsg:%s, length:%d, channel recv status:%d '%(backMsg, len(backMsg), self.channel.recv_ready())
        if len(backMsg) == 0 and self.channel.recv_ready() == False:
            break
```

but this still have a problem, if the channel cannot recv any reply from server within timeout, then the code will break the loop even if you want your code still run.

Comment: Well, *the question* is about `exec_command`. And you should not use `invoke_shell`/`send` to execute commands, unless you have some very specific circumstances.

Comment: then in what situation, i should use invoke_shell/send instead of exec_command?

Comment: See [What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848).