# Using paramiko, how could I get the stdout of exec_command() in real time instead of after completion?

Tags: python, paramiko

Using Python and paramiko, I have the following code

```
(stdin, stdout, stderr) = self.client.exec_command(x)
b = stderr.readlines()
if b:
    for i in b:
        print i
a = stdout.readlines()
if a:
    for i in a:
        print i
```

The command I run takes ~15 minutes and outputs a steady update to stdout, but it won't print on the host side until it's completed.

Is there a way to get the live stdout as opposed to waiting?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get output from a paramiko ssh exec\_command continuously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834743/get-output-from-a-paramiko-ssh-exec-command-continuously)

Answer (score 1):

Just repeatedly call `stdout.readlines()`. It will trigger flushing if any data in buffer.