# How to read the output of long running ssh command continuously without blocking using paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, stdout, nonblocking, paramiko

I am trying to read the output of a long-running ssh command continuously. I understand that `exec_command` is non-blocking. But as soon as I use `stdout.readlines()` it becomes blocking. I don't want to wait for 10 minutes for my ssh command to finish to read all the output lines. I want to get the output as soon as the ssh command writes in stdout. Is there a way to do it?

```
import paramiko
#import select
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password)
#transport = ssh.get_transport()
#channel = transport.open_session()
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
print stdout.readlines()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import paramiko
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password)
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(2048), ""):
    print(line)
```

The above code helped. I got this answer suggestion from 
[get output from a paramiko ssh exec_command continuously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834743/get-output-from-a-paramiko-ssh-exec-command-continuously)