# Check if stdout is empty? (Issue with stdout and readline())

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, stdout, readlines

The issue is with my code hanging in the for loop of this function. This function is called as a separate thread in a larger main script. After a user input, the main script sets `self.kill_switch`.

This code works great when stdout has a continuous output. the issue appears when stdout is empty the code hangs at `for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(), ""):` until stdout has a line of data. Once stdout has the information it writes the line of data and checks the kill_switch condition and exits according. How to set a timeout on the `for line` or check if stdout is empty?

Is there any way to set an `if` statement to have the code pass if stdout is blank?

```
def remote_connection(self):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command('python main_script.py', get_pty=True)
    while not self.kill_switch.is_set():
        for line in iter(lambda: stdout.readline(), ""):
            self.data.put(line)
            break
    self.ssh.exec_command('\x003', get_pty=True)
```

Comment: Take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834743/get-output-from-a-paramiko-ssh-exec-command-continuously Similar use case

Comment: Thanks. I looked at that case previously and implemented the second comment. Adding "get_pty=True" allowed me to read one line then proceed with the code. However, the code still stalls until it has a line of code to output. i.e. the for loop appears to still require some output before it will proceed and will not just return an empty line.

Comment: Suppose that stdout is going to receive the line `hello\n` in ten minutes. What would you have `stdout.readline()` return *now*, before the ten minutes expire?

Comment: Ideally it would not receive anything and just `pass` when there is no output in stdout. My thought is this would allow the code to continue and check the switch. Using this method I would simply use much shorter timeouts to check the stdout more frequently.